# What's the difference between iPhone and iPod for development?

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to develop an app for iOS that will run on iPhone and iPod, it doesn't require anything related to phone. iPhones are expensive so I'm thinking about purchasing just the latest iPod for development and when the app is finished I'll just borrow a friend's iPhone to test the app before delivering it to the client.

Would that be ok? The app is a simple app that will consume a web service and allow the user to search for products, write reviews etc etc. No hardware acceleration needed or any fancy thing needed.

Comment: Should be okay. But hard to give a definite answer without knowing what you are making.

Comment: thanks for helping instead of downvoting!

Comment: yeah, generally there shouldn't be much of a problem since both devices run iOS! however, you should be †esting in the simulator for different screen sizes as well.

Comment: @user3900456 normally I would have down voted. . This isn't really an SO question but phones are expensive and I can remember being worried about exactly the same thing when I got started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPhone and iPod are pretty much the same for development.  They both have a couple different screen sizes (with the iPhone having a few more), but if you use Auto Layout, issues relating to screen size shouldn't be issues.

The iPod is currently on an A5 processor, which doesn't have support for the Metal graphics framework, so if your aim is to develop for that (which it sounds like it isn't), then an actual iPhone with the A7 or A8 processor would be needed.

Some iPod Touches don't have cameras, such as the 8GB model that was available until recently, but if you use the APIs that let you check for the device's capabilities (instead of the device's product or model name), then you're applying defensive and adaptive coding techniques and you should be fine.

Based on your description, it sounds like you would be fine to start with the iOS Simulator itself, and then move on to borrowing an iPhone or iPod for testing purposes.

Good luck.